# Can multiple columns be created using one apply call

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create two columns based on dictionaries stored in another column

```py
df[[col1, col2]] = df[dict_data].apply(lambda x: x['col1_data'], x['col2_data'])
```

is this possible? Or should it be done in two separate lines?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your `apply(...)` wouldn't work since the `x['col2_data']` is not interpreted as part of the lambda but as a second parameter to the apply function. Thus, to get both to return from the lambda you would need to wrap them in an object e.g. either a `list()` like `[x['col1_data'], x['col2_data']` or a `tuple` like `(x['col1_data'], x['col2_data'])` or a `set` like `{x['col1_data'], x['col2_data'}`.

To achieve what you want to though you could do something like this:

*Given a pandas DataFrame defined as:*

```py
In[2] df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {'r1': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}, 'r2': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}}})
In[3] df
Out[3]: 
                     a
r1  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}
r2  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}
```

*You could do something as such:*

```py
df[['b', 'c']] = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: (x.a['k1'], x.a['k2']), axis=1).tolist(), index=df.index)
```

*Which will yield:*

```py
Out[6]: 
                     a  b  c
r1  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}  1  2
r2  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}  1  2
```

You could of course also achieve the same thing in two separate line which IMHO is cleaner and more efficient.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Using jniegsch's df example:

```
In[2] df = pd.DataFrame({'a': {'r1': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}, 'r2': {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}}})
In[3] df
Out[3]: 
                     a
r1  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}
r2  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}
```

Another way to do this is:

```
df[['b', 'c']] = pd.DataFrame(df.a.to_dict()).set_index(df.index)

    a                   b   c
r1  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}  1   1
r2  {'k1': 1, 'k2': 2}  2   2
```